# Magento 1.9 Rounding Issue Tax Calculation

Tags: magento-1.9, price, tax, rounding, tax-rounding

I have a product priced at £10.82 which gets 20% VAT added to it, leaving the price to be £12.98

This works fine when 1 product is in the cart but when more than 1  (e.g. 7) are added the calculation works like this

£10.82 * 7 = £75.74 (no problem here)
£75.74 * 1.2 = £90.888 (which is rounded to £90.89

When £12.98 * 7 = £90.86 (the correct amount). This is the figure I need to show not £90.89.

Comment: round($price,4) is also not working for me, what solution you applied for rounding issue?

Answer (score 2):

Change **Tax Calculation Method Based On** to **Unit Price** instead of **Total** under System > Configuration > Tax > Calculation Setting.

This will give you the tax calculation you'd like based on (£10.82 + (£10.82 * 0.2)) = £12.98 (rounded) * 7 = £90.86 rather than £75.74 + (£75.74 * 0.2) = £90.89.

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try copying `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php` to `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php` and change:

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 2);
}
```

for:

```
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 4);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried this and it hasn't changed anything. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: have you cleared cache after change this?

Comment: Cache is disabled, I've just flushed it to double check and its still the incorrect total, anything else I can try?

Comment: @lnelson92 any solution found for this as the round($price,4) is also not working for me.